# Teradata SQL - Union and Where Clause

Tags: sql

have a Teradata SQL UNION query and need to know how I can extract data from 2 tables where date in first part of UNION is before the date in the second part of the UNION query.  Example:

```
Select
name1,date1
from table1
UNION
Select
name2,date2
from table2
where date2 < date1
```

Would like to see only records where date2 is before date1.  This is just an example of what I need to retrieve from my data.

Select
Pat_Name, Provider, Clinic_Encounter_Date
from Clinic table
UNION
Pat_Name, Provider, Hosp_Encounter_Date
from Hospital table
where
Hosp_Encounter_Date < Clinic_Encounter_Date;

My SQL query runs fine, but when I add the WHERE clause I keep getting an error message. Teradata just doesn't like me!!!

Hopefully, this is a bit more helpful. :-)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Please edit your question with some examples of data.  Your question is not clear on what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLs in before and after the UNION are independent SQLs, so in the second statement it is not recognizing date1. i.e. the following statement is not valid.

```
Select name2,date2 from table2 where date2 < date1
```

You will need to change your statement to

```
Select
name1,date1
from table1
UNION
Select
name2,date2
from table2
where date2 < (select Min(date1) from table1)
```